# SQL where condition in Codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I want to check if booking exists or not.  I have checkin date, checkout date, and room number. I tried below query but it gives all the data which is not of that room id also. What am I doing wrong?

```
$array = array('checkin_date' => $checkin, 'checkout_date' => $checkin);
$array1 = array('checkin_date >' => $checkin, 'checkout_date <' => $checkin);
$array2 = array('checkin_date <' => $checkin, 'checkout_date >' => $checkin);
$array3 = array('checkin_date <' => $checkin, 'checkout_date <' => $checkin);
$array4 = array('checkin_date >=' => $checkin, 'checkout_date <=' => $checkin);
$array5 = array('checkin_date >=' => $checkout, 'checkout_date <=' => $checkout);

$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('igc_room_booking');
$this->db->where('delete_status', 0);
$this->db->where('cancel_status', 0);
$this->db->where('room_id', $val->room_id);
$this->db->where($array);
$this->db->or_where($array2);
$this->db->or_where($array3);
$this->db->or_where($array);
$this->db->or_where($array4);
$this->db->or_where($array5);
$bookingss = $this->db->get()->result();
```

Comment: What is `$val`?

Comment: You should echo your query and check it on phpmyadmin

Comment: what SQL version are you using ? you are overcomplicating things, probably a between would be enough in 1 condition.

Answer (score 0):

Right now i'm not thinking about your logic here - because Simos Fasouliotis said enough in the comments - so you get a right idea here in a syntactic way...

However, if you compile your query with `get_compiled_select` you get the following result:

```
SELECT *
FROM `igc_room_booking`
WHERE `delete_status` =0
AND `cancel_status` =0
AND `room_id` = 12
AND `checkin_date` = '2010-09-01'
AND `checkout_date` = '2010-09-01'
OR `checkin_date` < '2010-09-01'
OR `checkout_date` > '2010-09-01'
OR `checkin_date` < '2010-09-01'
OR `checkout_date` < '2010-09-01'
OR `checkin_date` = '2010-09-01'
OR `checkout_date` = '2010-09-01'
OR `checkin_date` >= '2010-09-01'
OR `checkout_date` <= '2010-09-01'
OR `checkin_date` >= '2010-10-01'
OR `checkout_date` <= '2010-10-01'
```

by now you should be able to understand whats the problem...

a possible solutions could be

```
$bookingss = $this->db
    ->select('*')
    ->from('igc_room_booking')
    ->where('delete_status', 0)
    ->where('cancel_status', 0)
    ->where('room_id', $val->room_id)
    ->group_start()
        ->or_where($array)
        ->or_where($array2)
        ->or_where($array3)
        ->or_where($array4)
        ->or_where($array5)
    ->group_end()
    ->get()
    ->result();
```

But imho that doesn't make any sense, you should clearly think about which date range you need...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$array = "('$checkindate' BETWEEN `checkin_date` AND `checkout_date`) OR  ('$checkoutdate' BETWEEN `checkin_date` AND `checkout_date`) OR (`checkin_date` > '$checkindate' AND `checkout_date` < '$checkoutdate')";
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('igc_room_booking');
    $this->db->where('delete_status', 0);
    $this->db->where('cancel_status', 0);
    $this->db->where('room_id', $val->room_id);
    $this->db->where($array);
    $bookingss = $this->db->get()->result();
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is that your query is wrong....you should remove

> $this->db->select(*) and $this->db->from('igc_room_booking')

and instead after all your where clauses you should have

> $this->db->get('igc_room_booking');